# Swift can't access part of JSON response with enum initializer

Tags: json, swift, decode

I have trouble accessing a part of a JSON response.

**(part of)The Source:**

```
{
"time":1552726518,
"result":"success",
"errors":null,
"responce":{
  "categories":{
     "1":{
        "nl":{
           "name":"New born",
           "description":"TEST",
           "children":[
              {
                 "name":"Unisex",
                 "description":"TESTe",
                 "children":[
                    {
                       "name":"Pants",
                       "description":"TEST",
                       "children":false
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

**Approach**
As you can see the source can have multiple categories. A single categorie will have a 'name', 'description' and may have 'children'. Children wil have a 'name', 'description' and also may have 'children'. This might go endless. If there are no children the SJON statement is 'false'

I use the website: https://app.quicktype.io to generate a junk of code to parse the JSON. I modified the result, because the website doesn't know that the children can go endless:

```
struct ProductCategories: Codable {
let time: Int?
let result: String?
let errors: [String]?
let responce: ProductCategoriesResponce?

init(time: Int? = nil, result: String? = nil, errors: [String]? = nil, responce: ProductCategoriesResponce? = nil) {

    self.time = time
    self.result = result
    self.errors = errors
    self.responce = responce
}
}

struct ProductCategoriesResponce: Codable {
let categories: [String: Category]?
}

struct Category: Codable {
let nl, en: Children?
}

struct Children: Codable {
let name, description: String?
let children: EnChildren?
}

enum EnChildren: Codable {
case bool(Bool)
case childArray([Children])

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    if let x = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
        self = .bool(x)
        return
    }
    if let x = try? container.decode([Children].self) {
        self = .childArray(x)
        return
    }
    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(EnChildren.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for EnChildren"))
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    switch self {
    case .bool(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    case .childArray(let x):
        try container.encode(x)
    }
}
}
```

And I can decode de data with:

```
productCategories = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProductCategories.self, from: jsonData!)
```

This part works fine. I can access "New Born", but can't get access his children. 
I search a long time for the answer I tried so much. To much to all share here. What I expect to get access is:

```
 if let temp = productCategories.responce?.categories?["\(indexPath.item)"]?.nl?.children! {
 let x = temp(from: Decoder)
```

but this will trow me an error:
"Cannot call value of non-function type 'EnChildren'"

also code like:

```
  let temp1 = productCategories.responce?.categories?["\(indexPath.item)"]?.nl?.children
```

Won't get me anywhere.

So, any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: If you are responsible for the server side, send `null` for the leaf children or omit the key rather than sending `false`. It makes the decoding process so much easier.

app.quicktype.io is a great resource but I disagree with its suggestion.

My solution uses a regular struct `Children` with a custom initializer. This struct can be used recursively.

The key `children` is decoded conditionally. First decode `[Children]`, on failure decode `Bool` and set `children` to `nil` or hand over the error.

And I declared struct members as much as possible as non-optional

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    let time: Date
    let result: String
    let errors: [String]?
    let responce: ProductCategories
}

struct ProductCategories: Decodable {
    let categories: [String: Category]
}

struct Category: Decodable {
    let nl: Children
}

struct Children: Decodable {
    let name, description: String
    let children : [Children]?

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case name, description, children }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
        do {
            children = try container.decode([Children].self, forKey: .children)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            _ = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .children)
            children = nil
        }
    }
}
```

In the root object the key `time` can be decoded to `Date` if you specify an appropriate date decoding strategy

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
let result = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: jsonData!)
```

And you can access for example the name `Unisex` with

```
result.responce.categories["1"]?.nl.children?[0].name
```